# Django NoReverseMatch at accounts/password_reset/

Tags: python, django

This seems like a common problem people are running into, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.  I've set up a URL:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name='login'),
    url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password_reset_done/$', auth_views.password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^auth/$', views.login_auth, name='login_auth'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register_user, name='register'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_user, name='logout'),
]
```

I try to link to the `password_reset` URL:

```
<a href="/accounts/password_reset/">Forgot Password?</a>
```

But it gives me the following error:

> NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password_reset/
>   Reverse for 'password_reset_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

This seems like a really simple bit of code, but it doesn't work.  I can successfully call `password_reset_done` using this exact method, but for some reason it doesn't work with `password_reset`.

[image]

Comment: Try this `url('^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, name='password_reset'),` note `$` apended in your url regex.

Comment: No luck changing that (although, you're right, the $ should be there)

Comment: I whink you're calling this url with using `'password_reset_done'` as name and it should be `'password_reset'`

Comment: Additionally, are you sure you're including the /accounts/ pages in your urls.py for the project?

Comment: Yes, /accounts is included.  All my other pages (login, register etc) are under /accounts.

Comment: @Gocht I don't see how I could be using `password_reset_done`.  This is like 2 lines of code, and I've copied it exactly from my project.

Comment: Can you show us in your original post the views in question and the urls.py? Snippets aren't too useful without the context.

Comment: I added the full code for `urls.py`.  I have no views for this though, as I am using the built in Django views (or trying to).

Comment: @TK-421 Sorry, I should have asked as well, in the DEBUG log, does it show where in the template rendering things are going wrong?

Comment: I added an image of the DEBUG screen.  Does that help?

Comment: I can't help but think something is missing outside of the urls (like a template or something). The Git repository shows a template being called when using the `password_reset_done` view. Can you try following this? http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html

Comment: I added an answer that solves the problem, but I get the exact same issue now, just with `password_reset_confirm`.  I feel like I'm in inception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `password_reset` line should look like this:

```
url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, {'post_reset_redirect' : '/accounts/password_reset_done/'}, name='password_reset'),
```